# Language Generation Feature - NodeJS - library unavailable

Tags: botframework

I have been looking at the experimental features for Bot Framework v4 and even though the documentation says NodeJS botbuilder-lg is available, npm cannot find it

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/language-generation

When will the NodeJS version be available

Asking clarification from the Bot Framework team.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't see the future.

Comment: Respectfully, I would like the Microsoft team or Bot Framework team to answer. I have done my research and we have a partnership with Microsoft so it was suggested that I post my question here. Down voting just hurts chances of that.

Comment: In that case, it is a customer support question, and thus also off-topic as per the FAQ: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/2988

Comment: The BotFramework Support Teams reviews all issues on StackOverflow with the [BotFramework Tag] regardless of how many votes it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get access to the BotFramework's daily builds, you need to configure npm to use the MyGet feed before installing the necessary packages. For more details take a look at the [BotBuilder MyGet Documentation](https://botbuilder.myget.org/feed/botbuilder-v4-js-daily/package/npm/botbuilder).

```sh
npm config set registry https://botbuilder.myget.org/F/botbuilder-v4-js-daily/npm/
```

That being said, I don't believe botbuilder-lg will be available for Node until v4.5 which I believe is scheduled for mid July. A pre-release might be available before then, but isn't currently.

Hope this helps.